# Ошибка: Undefined index

Tags: php, opencart

Создал в таблице `oc_product` столбец `sticker_new`.

Добавил в модель `product.php` в `addProduct` и `editProduct`.

`sticker_new = '" . (int)$data['sticker_new'] . "'`

В контроллере `product.php` добавил:

```
if (isset($this->request->post['sticker_new'])) {
    $data['sticker_new'] = $this->request->post['sticker_new'];
} elseif (!empty($product_info)) {
    $data['sticker_new'] = $product_info['sticker_new'];
} else {
    $data['sticker_new'] = '';
}
```

В `product_form.tpl` добавил:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <?php if ($sticker_new) { ?>
    <input class="sticker" type="checkbox" name="sticker_new" value="1" checked="checked" />
    <?php echo $text_sticker_new; ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <input class="sticker" type="checkbox" name="sticker_new" value="1" />
    <?php echo $text_sticker_new; ?>
    <?php } ?>
  </label>
</div>
```

На данный момент все работает правильно, но в ошибках вылезает такая PHP:

> Notice:  Undefined index: sticker_new in /system/storage/modification/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 150

Ошибка, если чекбокс не выбран.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что я сделал не так, почему данная ошибка появляется?

Comment: Зачем вообще так писать: `'" . (int)$data['sticker_new'] . "'` ? Здесь не требуется конкатенация, а нотис вылетает потому-что, данный ключ отсутствует в массиве `$data`. Для избежания нотиса, проверяйте через `isset` или `??`-для новых версий `php`.

Answer (score -1):

Ошибатор ругается на кешированные файлы. Может быть не обновились кеши контроллера или вьюхи? В любом случае стоит проверить - удалите папки с файлами кешей по адресу **`/system/storage/modification/`**

Comment: Это не помогло(